# Headless Dell PC no Audio Output

Tags: windows-7, audio, sound-card, headless

I have a basic Dell tower that is in my closet connected to a NAS which acts as a media server. I have a 3.5 mm cable from the headphones jack to my whole home audio system.

Without a monitor hooked up, there is no audio begin output at all. If I plug in headphones at the machine without a monitor, nothing.

If I plug in a monitor however, everything is fine.

Is there any way to trick the machine into thinking there is a monitor attached? I have no intention of putting a monitor on the shelf with it when I do everything remotely.

Comment: Where are you plugging the audio in when the monitor is connected? to the same jack, or into the monitor? How is your monitor connected? e.g. HDMI or Display Port, etc?

Comment: Also, how are you connecting to the machine when it's headless? Remote Desktop, VNC, etc?

Comment: When I had it on my desk, the monitor was hooked up to HDMI and I had the speakers hooked up to the front headphone jack. I tried the back audio slot as well and it worked perfectly fine in this setup. I then removed the monitor while it was still on my desk and the audio stopped working. I plugged in headphones and there was no output, until I plugged the monitor back in. When the monitor wsd unplugged, i used both RDC built into windows and teamviewer as options. Without remoting in however, there is no audio output without a monitor attached.

Comment: The two possibilities I was thinking are either the audio is defaulting to your HDMI connection (change default audio device), or the remote session is capturing the audio (change RDC settings). Neither one seem to be the case, but you might take a look to be sure.

Comment: Yeah, I have tested both of those variables by plugging in headphones when a monitor has been there, played a song and then removed the monitor. The sound was set to go through the headphone jack as the device and worked until the HDMI cable was removed. I also adjusted the power plan settings to make sure it wasn't thinking the computer was asleep and that didn't help either. Something so simple is so confusing as to why it wouldn't work correctly.

Comment: Do you still show an audio device when it's unplugged?

Comment: That's hard to tell when there's no monitor. When I remote in, it uses the audio source of the computer I log in from.

Comment: That doesn't seem right. You should be able to use the local audio source of the remote system. In RDC I see the options "Play on this computer", "Do not play", or "Play on remote computer". You'll want to select Play on remote computer. In device manager I still see the audio device the same as when I'm logged in locally.